# call url from java with special characters

Tags: java, url, character-encoding, utf8-decode

I have an URL with a special character, which I like to request, but URL is not recognized from JAVA.
URL : `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&titles=Iași&redirects=&lllimit=400`     ( Special Character is `ș` from the word Iași )

My Java Code :

```
String sWikiID="Iași";
String sArticleEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(sWikiID);
String sURL = "http://" + sFromLang + ".wikipedia.org" + "/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&titles=" + sArticleEncoded + "&redirects=&lllimit=400";
URL url = new URL(sURL);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define what sFromLang is, but check if this works for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String sFromLang="<add the value here>";
    String sWikiID="Iași";
    String sArticleEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(sWikiID, "UTF-8");
    String sURL = "http://" + sFromLang + ".wikipedia.org" + "/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&titles=" + sArticleEncoded + "&redirects=&lllimit=400";
    URL url = new URL(sURL);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UTF-8 or replace the ș with %C8%99 in your request.

Also, don't use .encode(String). It's deprecated. Instead, use .encode(String, Encode).

:)

Cindy